# Yii2 Masked Input datetime, dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm

Tags: date, datetime, yii2

I use [Yii2 maskedInput](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-maskedinput) for a datetime format into a form.

```
<?php
    echo $form->field($modelIsoTanksDeliveryOrder, "open_stack", [
        'template' => '{input}{error}{hint}'
    ])
        ->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'alias' => 'datetime',
                ],
                'options' => [
                    'placeholder' => '__-__-____ __:__'
                ]
            ]
        )->label(false)
?>
```

I am trying to change the behavior of the 'datetime' mask to use dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm instead of dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm.

I found the configuration ON JS [RobinHerbots](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/issues/589#issuecomment-50511999) 
But still failed on

```
->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
        'clientOptions' => [
            'alias' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            'separator' => "-",
        ],
        'mask' => '1-2-y h:s',
        'options' => [
            'placeholder' => '__-__-____ __:__'
        ]
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `alias` along with the `placeholder` and `separator` option for the `clientOptions` like below

```
<?php echo

    $form->field(
        $modelIsoTanksDeliveryOrder, "open_stack", [
            'template' => '{input}{error}{hint}'
        ]
    )->widget(
        \yii\widgets\MaskedInput::class, [
            'mask' => "1-2-y h:s",
            'clientOptions' => [
                'alias' => 'datetime',
                "placeholder" => "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm",
                "separator" => "-"
            ]
        ]
    );

?>
```

See more details int his [thread](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/issues/589)